# How to make this specific 3x5 layout with bootstrap?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, grid

I have been trying to make this layout for a long time now but I haven't been getting results.

It's a 3x5 grid, at least what is what I can see, not sure if it's 5x5 and 2 colunns are just invisible but still there.

[image]

I know bootstrap has a grid system, but I couldn't make use of it and get the desired result.

I got this:

```
<div class="row clearfix">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12" style="margin-left:2%">    
        <div class="single-profile-top wow fadeInDown" data-wow-duration="1000ms" data-wow-delay="300ms">
          <div class="row">
               <div class="col-md-20">
               COMPRESSORES SEMI-HERMÉTICOS
               </div>
               <div class="col-md-20">
               TUBOS E ACESSÓRIOS DE COBRE
               </div>
               <div class="col-md-20">
               DEPÓSITO DE LÍQUIDO  
               </div>
               <div class="col-md-20">
               ...
               </div>
               <div class="col-md-20">
               ...
               </div>
           </div>
           <div class="row">
               <div class="col-md-20">
               COMPRESSORES SEMI-HERMÉTICOS
               </div>
               <div class="col-md-20">
               TUBOS E ACESSÓRIOS DE COBRE
               </div>
               <div class="col-md-20">
               DEPÓSITO DE LÍQUIDO  
               </div>
               <div class="col-md-20">
               ...
               </div>
               <div class="col-md-20">
               ...
               </div>
           </div>
        </div>
    </div><!--/.col-lg-4 -->                    
</div> <!--/.row -->
```

Comment: I might be mistaken here, but bootstrap uses a base 12 grid. I don't understand why you're using .col-md-20 as you only have 12 columns to work with.

Comment: 12 by default. Though I doubt he has changed the default value

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4"></div>
        <div class="col-md-4"></div>
        <div class="col-md-4"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4"></div>
        <div class="col-md-4"></div>
        <div class="col-md-4"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4"></div>
        <div class="col-md-4"></div>
        <div class="col-md-4"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4"></div>
        <div class="col-md-4"></div>
        <div class="col-md-4"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4"></div>
        <div class="col-md-4"></div>
        <div class="col-md-4"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```